# intersection of three chords

Tags: geometry

On the circumference of circle Γ, chord AB with length 1100 is drawn. Let C be the midpoint of AB. Through C, 2 other chords DE and FG are also drawn, such that the points around the circle are A,D,F,B,E,G. The line segment AB intersects DG and FE (internally) at H and I, respectively. If AH=449, what is CI?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the [butterfly theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_theorem).